# How to insert objects into an ArrayList in alphabetical order?

Tags: java, arraylist

This seems similar to other questions here, but it is different because i am not looking to sort a pre-existing ArrayList. I'm looking to insert objects in, and as i am inserting the object in, i check to see if it is in alphabetical order or not. If it is not, i continue until the end of the arraylist and then i add it at the end of ArrayList.

There seems to be something wrong with the code that i already have, as when i run the test code there seems to be no objects being printed with my toString() method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CityDB {
    ArrayList<City>cityList = new ArrayList<>();


    public ArrayList<City> getCityList(){
        return cityList;
    }

    public void addCity(City city){
        for (int i=0; i<cityList.size();i++){
            if (cityList.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(city.getName().toLowerCase()) == 0){
                //city is the same as one of the cities in the list (case insensitive)
                //quit the loop (does not store two cities with same name)
                break;
            }else if (cityList.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(city.getName().toLowerCase()) <0 && cityList.get(i+1).getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(city.getName().toLowerCase()) >0){
                //city before is lexicographically lesser but city after is lexicographically more (case insensitive)
                cityList.add(i+1, city);
                //inserts at i+1, which is after the lexicographically smaller city, but is before the city which is lexicographically larger
                break;
            }else if (i == cityList.size()-1){
                cityList.add(city);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also add your toString method?

Comment: You haven't included any code which prints, or a toString method.

Comment: why have the last `if` - just add it

Comment: that is in my city class, is it necessary? i ll post the other class as well i guess.

Comment: and if you have only one city for example Madrid and you will then try to add Barcelona, when It will be added before Madrid?

Comment: Why don't you just add it and then sort the list with Collections.sort() ?

Comment: I would rather use a sortedList

Comment: Are you sure cityDb is getting populated?

Comment: I m not sure if i m allowed to use Collections.sort. My assignment states that the ArrayList has to store the cities in alphabetical order, does not store two cities with the same name and it takes City object as its parameter and adds city to CityList.

Comment: What happens when you add the first city? Nothing, your loop doesn't execute at all, so it doesn't get added. Your last if class needs to be outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the first `city` the size is zero. Your loop doesn't get executed.
*The conditions provided are broken*

```
for (int i=0; i<cityList.size();i++){
    if (cityList.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(city.getName().toLowerCase()) == 0){
        //city is the same as one of the cities in the list (case insensitive)
        //quit the loop (does not store two cities with same name)
        return;
    }else if (cityList.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(city.getName().toLowerCase()) <0 && cityList.get(i+1).getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(city.getName().toLowerCase()) >0){
            //city before is lexicographically lesser but city after is lexicographically more (case insensitive)
            cityList.add(i+1, city);
            //inserts at i+1, which is after the lexicographically smaller city, but is before the city which is lexicographically larger
            return;
    }

}
cityList.add(city);
```

Then you need to fix the conditions in your loop. First condition is ok, but consider the second condition:

```
cityList.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(city.getName().toLowerCase()) <0 
&& 
cityList.get(i+1).getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(city.getName().toLowerCase()) > 0
```

This does not need to be two parts. First check, if it is less than the current index, i, if it is less then you add it at that index. **Don't check `i+1`**

Comment: thanks. This really helped.
the final condition i am running is: 
cityList.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(city.getName().toLowerCase()) >0

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary search algorithm to find insertion index and write add method as below:

```
public void addCity(City city) {
        int insertionIndex = Collections.binarySearch(cityList, city, Comparator.comparing(City::getName));

        if (insertionIndex < 0) {
            insertionIndex = -(insertionIndex + 1);
        } else {
insertionIndex++;
        }

        cityList.add(insertionIndex, city);

    }
```

For better performance I suggest you to use LinkedList instead of ArrayList to store cities